# Different device Admob TestDevice

Tags: android, admob

Recently i have developed a android apps.
I test my device in my Android phone(HTC One s)
So what will be my ads:testDevices is emulator or something please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In the Logcat, you will find the device ID

plus when you connect the Device and press Play it will show the Device ID in the Emaulator or Device Selection.

To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("**")